# Customize CSS resize visual look

Tags: css

It is very convenient to allow a div to resize via something like this

```
div {
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But it is also very hard to see the resize button. Is there any way to

a) customize this

b) have a `<div>` element fixed to the bottom of a div via `bottom:0` that replicates this behavior? The div would have `width:100%` so that it appears as a bar across the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for pure CSS, but I am not sure that is possible so he is an alternative:

a) You can use Jquery Resizeable (https://jqueryui.com/resizable/) instead of just "resize: vertical", then you can style the icon however you want (since its just a div) with CSS using this:

```
.ui-icon, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {

}
```

b) You can do this with Jquery Resizable:

```
.ui-icon, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: (whatever you want here, maybe a down arrow?)
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
}
```